# Microsoft Dynamics UI Guidelines

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, ui-guidelines

SAP provides [UI Guidelines for CRM WebClient User Interface](http://www.sapdesignguild.org/resources/CRM-UI-Guidelines-Customers.pdf). Is there something similar for Microsoft Dynamics CRM or Microsoft Dynamics in general?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078975/how-to-understand-microsoft-dynamics-products

Comment: UI Guidelines sounds very different to the other question (product comparison)... I don't think it is a dup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Download the [Microsoft CRM 4.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38) which includes, among other things, the CRM 4.0 UI style guide, which sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Also [User experience (UX) guidelines for Windows, Dynamics NAV and AX](http://www.uxpassion.com/2009/06/user-experience-ux-guidelines-for-windows-dynamics-nav-dynamics-ax/)

Answer (score 1):

There is a [user interface guideline](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa662849.aspx) for Dynamics CRM 3.0 as well as [UI style guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150858.aspx) for dynamics CRM 4.0

Hope this helps,

hadi

Answer (score -2):

Here is the URL of the latest UI Design Guidelines for Microsoft Dynamics CRM: **[Guidelines](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/9/95991807-78B5-42FF-B7A0-29B74BADDE32/CRM_UX_Design_Guidelines.pdf)**